# Why Cant insert/use ::BEFORE ::AFTER css styles?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I am trying to use:

```
.widget::before{
  background:red;
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
  content: "";   <---- if this is removed, then block is not visible at all
}
```

but without **`content: "";`** the pseudo-block is not displayed at all.. should the pseudo-class always include the `content` parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Without `content: '';` there is nothing to be added before the widget.  You can declare the size, color, shape, etc of the pseudo class... but without declaring what the 'content' is, there is nothing to insert.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should.
CSS Pseudo elements are for adding content to the page, thus they have to have content to be displayed.
[According to the Docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content):

> This property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements to generate content in a document. Values have the following meanings:
>   **none**:
>       The pseudo-element is not generated.

That Implies that pseudo elements **must** have content to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using ::before and ::after pseudo classes is to insert content using CSS. If content property is not declared for pseudo class, there wont be any change will be visible